# resolving race condition on API call

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, race-condition, use-effect

I'm having a problem that seems to be due to an async call. I have an action that makes an API call and pushes to a Dashboard page. That API call also updates `state.account.id` based on the response it gives back:

```
const submitLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.loginAndGetAccount(credentials);
        props.history.push('/protected');
        e.target.reset();
    }
```

`loginAndGetAccount` is coming from this action:

```
export const loginAndGetAccount = credentials => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_ACCOUNT_START })
    axios
        .post('https://foodtrucktrackr.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login/operators', credentials)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            dispatch({ type: GET_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, payload: res.data.id })
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

On the Dashboard page, I have useEffect set up to make another API call dynamically based on the value held in `state.account.id`. However, it seems the first API call is pushing to the Dashboard page before the response comes back and updates `state.account.id`. Therefore, when the second API call is made there, it's passing `state.account.id` to that dynamic API call as undefined, which, of course, results in a failed call. How can I resolve this?
Here's what's happening:

```
const Dashboard = props => {
    const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
            console.log(props.accountId);
            axiosWithAuth()
                .get(`/operator/${props.accountId}`)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is the Dashboard component</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        accountId: state.account.id
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Dashboard);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you are making a request here, but not

```
export const loginAndGetAccount = credentials => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_ACCOUNT_START })
    axios
        .post('https://foodtrucktrackr.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login/operators', credentials)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            dispatch({ type: GET_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, payload: res.data.id })
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

waiting for it to complete here before you navigate to the next page

```
const submitLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.loginAndGetAccount(credentials);
        props.history.push('/protected');
        e.target.reset();
    }
```

the quickest way to fix this is to returnt the promise from `loginAndGetAccount` and then `props.history.push` in the resolution of that promise...

like this:

```
export const loginAndGetAccount = credentials => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_ACCOUNT_START })
    // return the promise here
    return axios
        .post('https://foodtrucktrackr.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login/operators', credentials)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            dispatch({ type: GET_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, payload: res.data.id })
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

...


const submitLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.loginAndGetAccount(credentials)
        .then(() => {
            // so that you can push to history when it resolves (the request completes)
            props.history.push('/protected');
            e.target.reset();
        }
        .catch(e => {
            // handle the error here with some hot logic
        })
}
```

Comment: This worked, only that the result fn can't be in the resolution of the promise, has to be outside. Also, I realized that I could just put props.accountId inside the dependency array in the useEffect hook and then use an if statement to check for props.accountId before running the fn inside the useEffect hook. Both ways work.

Comment: True both work for the happy path, but what about when the login request fails and you already routed them to the dashboard route? Are you going to route them back and display an error message on the login page?

I think it would be better to catch the returned promise in the submitLogin before routing them to another location. So that you can display the error text there and not allow them to proceed without a successful login